# How to delete a whole file from firebase storage - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

This is how my DB looks like:
[image]

and I wanna delete everything on that file.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("User ($uid)/ads").delete();
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("User ($uid)/ProfilePic").delete();
```

the second line deletes the `ProfilePic`, but the first line returns an error.
I'm new to firebase and flutter so bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no firebase API to delete all the files with a certain prefix i.e. files you see in the console within a certain folder.

One way to achieve this is by using `listAll()` method to fetch all the files with certain prefix and delete them individually later.

Flutter firebase storage `listAll()` method is currently available in `dev` version of package, in version `5.0.0-dev.1`, which you can use as shown below:

```
firebase_storage.ListResult result =
      await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().listAll();
```

After using `listAll()`, you'll get all the files and then you can delete them individually.

Additionally, you can delete files on your backend server also.